# Drag and drop for images in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, images, imgur, uploader

We have it for questions and answers (regular posts)

[image]

How come it doesn't exist for chat.

[image]

(I know that it is most likely less common to be uploading images to chat, however on certain chat rooms, images are uploaded frequently)

I find it very annoying when uploading to chat to have to start going through my folders on my pc to find the image, usually I have it right there on my desktop and it's very convenient to just *Drag and drop*

I think it's a much needed feature.